# I wonder how i'm getting the Error "Notice: undefined variable", when I redirect to main page after inserting values to db

Tags: php, mysql

```
This is my php code
       <?php
$host = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "";
$db_name = "test1";
$tbl_name = "test_mysql";

mysql_connect("$host", "$username", "$password")or die("cannot connect");
mysql_select_db("$db_name")or die("cannot select DB");
$name = (isset($_POST['name'])) ? $_POST['name'] : '';
$lastname = (isset($_POST['lastname'])) ? $_POST['lastname'] : '';
$email = (isset($_POST['email'])) ? $_POST['email'] : '';
$sql = "INSERT INTO $tbl_name(name, lastname, email)VALUES('$name', '$lastname', '$email')";
$result = mysql_query($sql);

if ($result) {
    echo "Successful";
    echo "<BR>";
    echo "<a href='insert_ac.php'>Back to main page</a>";
} else {
    echo "ERROR";
}
mysql_close();`enter code here`

?>
```

I am able to insert values to db,but after that if i click "back to main page" to insert more, i am getting the errors as shown below

```
Notice: Undefined variable: name in      C:\xampp\htdocs\PhpProject3(Insert)\insert_ac.php on line 25
Notice: Undefined variable: lastname in C:\xampp\htdocs\PhpProject3(Insert)\insert_ac.php on line 25
Notice: Undefined variable: email in C:\xampp\htdocs\PhpProject3(Insert)\insert_ac.php on line 25
```

Successfully Inserted 
To insert more...Back to main page 
How can I fix this???

Comment: share  `insert_ac.php` code if different from current code ?

Comment: Thanks..the problem was with where i am redirecting.i was trying to redirect to the same page

Answer (score 1):

Before you put `$_POST` variables in a database you need to check and validate them thouroughly.

```
// start by making all posted varibales local, this is safe because of the prefix
extract($_POST,EXTR_PREFIX_ALL,'post');
// first check if all wanted variables exist
if (isset($post_name) &&
    isset($post_lastname) &&
    isset($post_email))
{
  // now make the variables safe for insertion
  $name     = mysql_real_escape_string($post_name);
  $lastname = mysql_real_escape_string($post_lastname);
  $email    = mysql_real_escape_string($post_email);
  // only then insert them in the database
  $sql      = "INSERT INTO $tbl_name (name,lastname,email) 
               VALUES ('$name','$lastname','$email')";
  $result   = mysql_query($sql);
  echo ($result ? 'Success' : 'Failure');
}
```

I left out a few bits, like making the db connection.

**The mysql extension is deprecated, please do not use it.**

Answer (score 0):

Well, maybe define it even if it didn't get a value? You should know what you want to do if there is no POST data.

```
if(isset($_POST['name'])){
  $name = $_POST['name'];
}else{
  $name='';
}
```

Comment: This is only half solution because when form is not send your code will add empty values into db

Comment: Yes, this is why i said he should know what he wants to do without data :)

Comment: @MaryAnn Then you did it wrong again.

Answer (score 0):

You should put data into db **only** after data are send by post, so you must first check if form is send:

```
if (!empty($_POST)) { //HERE you check if form is send

if(isset($_POST['name'])){ $name = $_POST['name']; } 
if(isset($_POST['lastname'])){ $lastname = $_POST['lastname']; } 
if(isset($_POST['email'])){ $email = $_POST['email']; } 
$sql="INSERT INTO $tbl_name(name, lastname, email)VALUES('$name', '$lastname', '$email')";
$result=mysql_query($sql);
if($result){
echo "Successful";
echo "<BR>";
echo "<a href='insert_ac.php'>Back to main page</a>";
}
else {
echo "ERROR";
}
}
?>
```

Comment: 'This is only half solution because when form is not send your code will add empty values into db'

So if I POST something but not name lastname email, it still inserts empty values. 'half answer'

Comment: It will happen only happen when author will have wrong form or he will be attacked. if you want, you can check all fields and if all exists then make insert. But for this moment I think it resolve author problem.

Answer (score 0):

Use `ternary operator` or assign blank value through `if else` statement. You need to assign default value to variable.

Try this one `:`

```
<?php
$host = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "";
$db_name = "test1";
$tbl_name = "test_mysql";

mysql_connect("$host", "$username", "$password")or die("cannot connect");
mysql_select_db("$db_name")or die("cannot select DB");
$name = (isset($_POST['name'])) ? $_POST['name'] : '';
$lastname = (isset($_POST['lastname'])) ? $_POST['lastname'] : '';
$email = (isset($_POST['email'])) ? $_POST['email'] : '';
$sql = "INSERT INTO $tbl_name(name, lastname, email)VALUES('$name', '$lastname', '$email')";
$result = mysql_query($sql);

if ($result) {
    echo "Successful";
    echo "<BR>";
    echo "<a href='insert_ac.php'>Back to main page</a>";
} else {
    echo "ERROR";
}
mysql_close();
```

Comment: Here, if i click on  "back to main page" its not redirecting

Comment: Now i am able to add data to db, but the problem is with redirection..which can be corrected by changing insert_ac.php,where i am redirecting to same page..Thanks for the help!!